# Applescript Excel Date cell value not displaying correctly

Tags: applescript

When I use the following Applescript (which I found on StackOverflow :)), it works great except that the cell the script selects is a date but it does not display it correctly at the applescript. Perhaps this will help:

```
set searchRange to range ("D1:D100")
set foundRange to find searchRange what "string" with match case
set fRow to first row index of foundRange
set myData to value of range ("B" & fRow as text)
```

The value of the selected cell in column B is 4:14:00 AM but in AppleScript, it returns as 0.176388888889

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

That seems to be the way Excel stores the data internally. Try using `string value` instead of `value`. That worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is answered, but just to add out of interest: Excel stores time as a decimal fraction, and the formatting makes it meaningful. So noon is 0.5, and in theory, 24:00:00 would be 1, but obviously time rolls round to 00:00:00 again. If you multiply your 04:14:00 by 86400 (the number of seconds in a day), it will reveal the time in seconds. So you can see how to do maths with time, and how Excel does maths in the background.

Dates are stored as integers, counting up from 01/01/1901 (1), where today's date is stored as 41601.

To see the stored value just change the cell format to 'general' (cmd+1, useful shortcut).